# Unable to cast a list

Tags: c#, list

I am getting a error in the line below.

```
 temp.day1_veh_p = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, day1.Where(x => x.plannedTriips == 1).Select(x => new {value=x.vehicleNumber+":"+x.shiftCompletedOn }).Cast<string>().ToArray());
```

Th error Message being

```
Unable to cast object of type '<>f__AnonymousType0`1[System.String]' to type 'System.String'.
```

The list day1 is of type

```
public class tripDetails
{
    public string accountID { get; set; }
    public string supplierName { get; set; }
    public string supplierCode { get; set; }
    public DateTime shiftFrom { get; set; }
    public DateTime shiftTo { get; set; }
    public int plannedTriips { get; set; }
    public int actualTrips { get; set; }
    public DateTime forDate { get; set; }
    public string vehicleNumber { get; set; }
    public string shiftCompletedOn { get; set; }
    public class Comparer : IEqualityComparer<tripDetails>
    {
        public bool Equals(tripDetails x, tripDetails y)
        {
            return x.supplierCode == y.supplierCode;
        }

        public int GetHashCode(tripDetails obj)
        {
            return (obj.supplierCode).GetHashCode();
        }
    }
}
```

What exactly Am i doing wrong??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is the `new { value = ... }`

Replace:

```
Select(x => new {value=x.vehicleNumber+":"+x.shiftCompletedOn }).Cast<string>()
```

with

```
Select(x => x.vehicleNumber+":"+x.shiftCompletedOn)
```

and you're sorted. You won't need the `Cast<string>()` at all.

Your original code creates, for each record, a new instance of an anonymous type that has a member called `value` with the string desired; the second version just creates the string.

In a way, it is no different to trying this:

```
class Foo
{
    public string Bar {get;set;}
}
...
var foo = new Foo { Bar = "abc" };
string s = (string)foo; // doesn't compile
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes, an anonymous type is not a string, so replace this

```
 .Select(x => new { value = x.vehicleNumber + ":" + x.shiftCompletedOn })
```

with

```
 .Select(x => x.vehicleNumber + ":" + x.shiftCompletedOn)
```

Then you can use the query(you don't need to create a new array) for `string.Join`.

It's also helpful to use multiple lines, it makes your code much more readable:

```
var vehicles = day1.Where(x => x.plannedTriips == 1)
              .Select(x => x.vehicleNumber + ":" + x.shiftCompletedOn);
string str = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, vehicles);
```

Answer (score 3):

Replace this

```
(x => new {value=x.vehicleNumber+":"+x.shiftCompletedOn }).Cast<string>()
```

by this

```
(x => String.Format("{0}\:{1}", x.vehicleNumber, x.shiftCompletedOn))
```

When you are doing `new { ... }` you are creating items of anonymous type and then (`Cast<string()`) trying explicitly cast to `string` and such conversion is not defined - youn ends up with appropriate exception.